# How to manipulate Openflow data packet to change IP adresses?

Tags: sdn, openflow

I want to change the IP addresses of source and destination using Pox controller.
Is there any algorithm to fulfill my requirement and where to place it in Pox ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The function you are looking for is Network Address Translation (NAT), which you would most likely need to use the `misc.nat` tool.

The usage is documented in `nat.py` located here: https://github.com/noxrepo/pox/blob/eel/pox/misc/nat.py

Comment: Thanks benjamin for your beneficial opinion,  i need your more help regarding the scenario i have proposed. In my scenario there is one controller and one  open flow switch connected with three hosts .i want to ping h3 from h1 and below is the flow table i am adding to switch for changing the IP adresses or changing the flow table so that at return H3 can directly send data to H1.

Comment: Here is the algorthim that i put in Ovs switch as text file  using the command as "sh ovs-ofctl add-flows s1 text.txt     " the file was saved as the name of text in mininet folder which are as "

Answer (score 0):

e 0 - Access Control
table=0,ip,nw_src=10.0.0.0/24,nw_dst=10.0.0.0/24,actions=resubmit(,1)
table=0,arp,nw_src=10.0.0.0/24,nw_dst=10.0.0.0/24,actions=resubmit(,1)
table=0,icmp,nw_src=10.0.0.1,nw_dst=30.0.0.3,actions=resubmit(,1)
table=0,tcp,nw_src=10.0.0.1,nw_dst=30.0.0.3,tp_dst=80,actions=resubmit(,1)
table=0,ip,nw_src=30.0.0.3,actions=resubmit(,1)
table=0,priority=0,actions=drop

## table 1 - NAT

table=1,ip,nw_src=10.0.0.1,nw_dst=30.0.0.3,actions=mod_nw_src=5.5.5.5,resubmit(,2)
table=1,ip,nw_src=30.0.0.3,nw_dst=5.5.5.5,actions=mod_nw_dst=10.0.0.1,resubmit(,2)
table=1,priority=0,actions=resubmit(,2)

## table 2 - forward/route

table=2,ip,nw_dst=10.0.0.1,actions=mod_dl_dst=00:00:00:00:00:01,output:1
table=2,ip,nw_dst=10.0.0.2,actions=mod_dl_dst=00:00:00:00:00:02,output:2
table=2,ip,nw_dst=30.0.0.3,actions=mod_dl_dst=00:00:00:00:00:03,output:3
priority=0,table=2,arp,nw_dst=10.0.0.1,actions=output:1
priority=0,table=2,arp,nw_dst=10.0.0.2,actions=output:2